# How is the implicit segment register of a near pointer determined?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, cpu-registers, segments

In section 4.3 of [*Intel 64® and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual. Volume 1: Basic Architecture*](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/), it says:

> A near pointer is a 32-bit offset ... within a segment. Near pointers are used for all memory references in a flat memory model or for references in a segmented model where the identity of the segment being accessed is implied.

This leads me to wondering: how is the implied segment register determined?

I know that `(%eip)` and displaced `(%eip)` (e.g. `-4(%eip)`) addresses use `%cs` by default, and that `(%esp)` and displaced `(%esp)` addresses use `%ss`, but what about `(%eax)`, `(%edx)`, `(%edi)`, `(%ebp)` etc., and can the implicit segment register depend also on the instruction that the memory address operand appears in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than  `CS` and `SS` register accesses that you mentioned, most other accesses will use the `DS` segment register.  A couple exceptions that I can recall:

- the string-oriented instructions will use the `ES` for the 'destination' (implicitly addressed by the `EDI` register) segment register
- memory accesses using the `EBP` register as a 'base address' register will use the `SS` segment register.  However, if the `EBP` register is used as a scaled index register, the segment used will be `DS` (unless the base address register is `ESP`)